# git pull added a whole new subdirectory of old files?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm a git idiot, I guess.

I always thought git should be simple in my personal use. I just usually want one branch, all I really wanna do is upload files to the web and be able to download them back-and-forth between my laptop and desktop.

Today I was working on one of my projects for a long while (about hours long) and I wanted to push my changes. My git has been acting wonky recently, I usually end up having to force git pushes because git seems to think my local files aren't matching with the repo online; even though I haven't pushed changes from any other machine (I think?)

This is usually the command I use to push to the repo if git gives me any misgivings:

```
git add -A && git commit -m "message"
git push
```

I am familiar with commiting only the files I have changed, and adding files by their names, but for my personal stuff, sometimes I just want quick results. If it's not my repo, I will follow the directions that the admin of the repo expects.

So, this time, I can't git push, it's recommending that I do a git pull first. Fine, okay, what's the harm anyway? Well, I thought git pull had rewrote all my local files with the ones from the repo and I completely freaked out for half an hour -- until I later discovered that it hadn't overwritten anything, it instead created a copy of the subdirectory (and all its files) that was inside the root repo directory (basically all of the old files that were there before my changes).

Why did it do that? Thinking about it now, I guess it was smart for git to do that, because it feels safe to just have a back up of all the old files. But I've never seen this before and it totally caught me off guard.

So after that, I backed up all my files, then I deleted the subdirectory that git had added, then did another git push. After that, I looked back at my repo and it says I deleted a bunch of files. I have no idea why. But it seems like all the files I want to be there are actually there. So it seems like everything has worked out in the end.

At some point, I *really really* need to read up on git thoroughly and get comfortable with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Git is like a butler, it won't do anything on its own unless you tell it to.  If files/folders were moving around when you did a `git pull`, then either you or someone else pushed those changes to the remote repository, and you then brought them in.  The usual way to resolve the error message you get is to just `git pull`.  If you _can't_ do that for some reason, then you fix that reason first.

Comment: "At some point, I really really need to read up on git thoroughly". Definitely a better option to look at the docs than to ask a question without providing any actually useful information.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Maybe a little more useful than your comment though :P
Question is, do you want to look through all the "useful information"? I copy and pasted all hundreds of lines of git, do you want to look at it?
 Seriously, I ask because most of the time people are complaining that my posts are too long.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Okay, I should ask: what information would you like to see that would make it more useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it created a subfolder when you executed git pull, that’s mainly caused the folder structure in remote repo is different from the structure in your local repo.

When you execute `git pull`, git will get the commits (which not exist in your local repo) from remote and merge these changes to your local repo. And if there has conflict files, you should manually resolve the conflicts and continue to merge.

And when you push again after delete and add some files ("I backed up all my files, then I deleted the subdirectory that git had added, then did another git push. After that, I looked back at my repo and it says I deleted a bunch of files"), the reason why you didn’t push successful as below:

- You should make sure the working tree is not in merging process (if there has conflicts after `git pull`). To check if you are in merging process, you can use the command `git status`. If the output shows items for **unmerged  paths**, you should finish the merge by `git add .` and `git commit`.
- If you are not in merging process, you should check if the working tree is clean by `git status`. If the working tree is clean, then push your changes to remote repo.

Besides, below commands may be helpful when you working in git repo:

- **`git status`**: help you to check if the working tree is clean, and provide the relation (ahead/behind) for the tracking branch.
- **`git add .`**: add all the files (untrackes, changes not to be committed, confilct etc) into stage state.
- **`git push -f`**: force push to remote.